# Golang GORM query locations around a position with Lat and Lng

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to make a specific request with [GORM](http://gorm.io).

Here are the tables I use:

```
+-------------------+
| Tables            |
+-------------------+
| locations         |
| shops             |
| shops_tags        |
| tags              |
+-------------------+
```

*Locations table*

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| shop_id    | bigint(20)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lat        | decimal(10,8)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lng        | decimal(11,8)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

*Location model*

```
type Location struct {
    gorm.Model
    ShopID int64
    Shop   Shop
    Lat    float64 `gorm:"type:decimal(10,8)"`
    Lng    float64 `gorm:"type:decimal(11,8)"`
}
```

*Shops table*

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(180)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| active      | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

*Shop model*

```
type Shop struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string      `json:"name" gorm:"type:varchar(180);unique_index"`
    Active      int         `json:"active" gorm:"type:tinyint(1);default:1"`
    Tags        []*Tag      `json:"tags" gorm:"many2many:shops_tags;"`
    Locations   []Location  `json:"locations" gorm:"locations"`
}
```

*Tag model*

```
type Tag struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name  string  `json:"name" gorm:"type:varchar(180)"`    
    Shops []*Shop `json:"shops" gorm:"many2many:shops_tags;"`
}
```

*Handler to return query in JSON*

```
func GetShops(c echo.Context) error {
    db := db.DbManager()

    // Get POST data (name lat and lng)
    type geo struct {
        Lat string `json:"lat" form:"lat" query:"lat"`
        Lng string `json:"lng" form:"lng" query:"lng"`
    }

    // Bind request body
    g := new(geo)
    if err := c.Bind(g); err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusForbidden, err)
    }

    shops := []model.Shop{}

    // Totally disordered attempt of a query with `go-gorm` to display the list of nearby shops, sorted by the distance between us.

    db.Preload("Locations", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {

        // How here use  g.Lat and g.Lng for this request  

        return db.Order("locations.id DESC").Limit(1)
    }).Preload("Tag").Find(&shops)

    // Json
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, echo.Map{
        "shops": &shops,
    })
}
```

So we have **Stores**, which have **Locations**, we want to display **Stores** within 15km of our **Location**. Only the **last location** is useful, that's why, we limited the results to 1 in decreasing order.

*Edit*

Thanks to [@Rick James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766831/rick-james) for suggesting me to rephrase my question, here is the query in `MYSQL`, how to adapt it to `go-gorm`:

```
SELECT
shops.id,
    shops.name, (
        (
            6371.04 * ACOS(
                (
                    (
                        COS(
                            (
                                (
                                    PI() / 2
                                ) - RADIANS(
                                    (90 - locations.lat)
                                )
                            )
                        ) * COS(
                            PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - -33.73788500)
                        ) * COS(
                            (
                                RADIANS(locations.lng) - RADIANS('151.23526000')
                            )
                        )
                    ) + (
                        SIN(
                            (
                                (
                                    PI() / 2
                                ) - RADIANS(
                                    (90 - locations.lat)
                                )
                            )
                        ) * SIN(
                            (
                                (
                                    PI() / 2
                                ) - RADIANS(90 - -33.73788500)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ) AS 'distance',
    locations.id AS 'location_id',
    locations.shop_id,
    locations.lat,
    locations.lng,
    locations.created_at
FROM
shops
INNER JOIN locations ON(
    locations.created_at >= '2017-12-13'
    AND(
        (
            6371.04 * ACOS(
                (
                    (
                        COS(
                            (
                                (
                                    PI() / 2
                                ) - RADIANS(
                                    (90 - locations.lat)
                                )
                            )
                        ) * COS(
                            PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - -33.73788500)
                        ) * COS(
                            (
                                RADIANS(locations.lng) - RADIANS('151.23526000')
                            )
                        )
                    ) + (
                        SIN(
                            (
                                (
                                    PI() / 2
                                ) - RADIANS(
                                    (90 - locations.lat)
                                )
                            )
                        ) * SIN(
                            (
                                (
                                    PI() / 2
                                ) - RADIANS(90 - -33.73788500)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ) < '500'
    AND shops.id = (locations.shop_id)
)
WHERE
  shops.active = 1
GROUP BY
  shops.id
ORDER BY
  distance ASC
LIMIT
  100
```

Comment: I am confused by the syntax here:  `..., shop_id ( ...` -- This implies that `shop_id` is some kind of function.  Yet `( ... ) as distanct` makes sense.  Perhaps a comma is missing after `shop_id`?

Comment: `Order("locations.id DESC").Limit(1)` talks about `id`, yet two other things talk about `distance`.

Comment: hi, thanks for your message, if you look at the structure of the tables, the stores have locations, they are stores that regularly change locations.

Comment: And my question about the `shop_id`?

Comment: To define a belongs to relationship, the foreign key must exists, default foreign key uses owner’s type name plus its primary key.

For a above example, to define a model that belongs to Shop, the foreign key should be ShopID (`shop_id`).

Comment: Don't you get a syntax error?

Comment: I do not have any errors, I just got the right result from the `Go` code, indeed I wish to have the list of stores sort by last locations around a lat / lng

Comment: Are you asking how to write a `JOIN` in SQL?

Comment: Absolutely not, I ask how to do the query with `go-gorm` it's not a SQL problem but a `go-gorm` knowledge.

Comment: I asked your help to make this request with the ORM, to improve my knowledge.

Comment: `<opinion>`Alas, I know nothing about ORMs.  Unfortunately, with most 3rd party packages that _try_ to insulate the programmer from SQL, the programmer still needs to learn SQL in order to achieve anything other than trivial queries.`</opinion>`  So, I was approaching your question from "here's the SQL, now figure out how to reverse engineer it to ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the query I would definitely hand craft this one and not rely on any ORM to execute the query. Refer to using the Exec method on a gorm database instance [ref](http://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html).

But...
To use an ORM like gorm, using gorm's SQL-Builder is a possibility. Here is an example that should be of guidance. Please note that this is for SQLite Database, and not for MYSQL so the functions in use do not exist. We are mainly concerned with building the query.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
)

const (
    layoutISO = "2006-01-02"
)

type Shop struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name      string     `json:"name" gorm:"type:varchar(180);unique_index"`
    Active    int        `json:"active" gorm:"type:tinyint(1);default:1"`
    Tags      []Tag      `json:"tags" gorm:"many2many:shops_tags;"`
    Locations []Location `json:"locations" gorm:"locations"`
}

type Tag struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name  string `json:"name" gorm:"type:varchar(180)"`
    Shops []Shop `json:"shops" gorm:"many2many:shops_tags;"`
}

type Location struct {
    gorm.Model
    ShopID int64
    Shop   Shop
    Lat    float64 `gorm:"type:decimal(10,8)"`
    Lng    float64 `gorm:"type:decimal(11,8)"`
}

// Get POST data (name lat and lng)
type geo struct {
    Lat float64 `json:"lat" form:"lat" query:"lat"`
    Lng float64 `json:"lng" form:"lng" query:"lng"`
}

var distance_calculation = `
       (
           (
                   6371.04 * ACOS(((COS(((PI() / 2) - RADIANS((90 - locations.lat)))) *
                                    COS(PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - ?)) *
                                    COS((RADIANS(locations.lng) - RADIANS(?))))
                   + (SIN(((PI() / 2) - RADIANS((90 - locations.lat)))) *
                      SIN(((PI() / 2) - RADIANS(90 - ?))))))
               )
           )`

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "test.db")
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    defer db.Close()
    // Enable Logger, show detailed log
    db.LogMode(true)

    // Migrate the schema
    db.AutoMigrate(&Shop{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Tag{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Location{})


    g := new(geo)
    g.Lat = -33.73788500
    g.Lng = 151.23526000
    type Result struct {
        ID         uint
        Name       string
        Distance   int
        LocationID uint
        ShopID     uint
        Lat        float64
        Lng        float64
        CreatedAt  time.Time
    }

    date, _ := time.Parse(layoutISO, "2017-12-13")
    var t []Result
    err = db.Table("Shops").
        Select("shops.id, shops.name, locations.id AS 'location_id', locations.shop_id, locations.lat, locations.lng, locations.created_at, "+
            distance_calculation+" as distance\n", g.Lat, g.Lng, g.Lat).
        Joins("inner join locations on shops.id = locations.shop_id\n").
        Where(&Shop{Active: 1}).
        Where("locations.created_at >= CAST(strftime('%s', ?) AS INT) * 1000", date).
        Where(distance_calculation + " < ?", g.Lat, g.Lng, g.Lat, 500).
        Group("\nshops.id\n").
        Order("locations.id DESC\n").
        Limit(100).Scan(&t).Error
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", t)
}
```

Query Built with SQL Builder

```sh
(C:/Users/fakename/source/stackoverflow/go/geo-go-gorm/main.go:97)
[2019-10-31 15:36:37]  [1.00ms]  SELECT shops.id, shops.name, locations.id AS 'location_id', locations.shop_id, locations.lat, locations.lng, locations.created_at,
       (
           (
                   6371.04 * ACOS(((COS(((PI() / 2) - RADIANS((90 - locations.lat)))) *
                                    COS(PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - -33.737885)) *
                                    COS((RADIANS(locations.lng) - RADIANS(151.23526))))
                   + (SIN(((PI() / 2) - RADIANS((90 - locations.lat)))) *
                      SIN(((PI() / 2) - RADIANS(90 - -33.737885))))))
               )
           ) as distance
 FROM "Shops" inner join locations on shops.id = locations.shop_id
 WHERE ("shops"."active" = 1) AND (locations.created_at >= CAST(strftime('%s', '2017-12-13 00:00:00') AS INT) * 1000) AND (
       (
           (
                   6371.04 * ACOS(((COS(((PI() / 2) - RADIANS((90 - locations.lat)))) *
                                    COS(PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - -33.737885)) *
                                    COS((RADIANS(locations.lng) - RADIANS(151.23526))))
                   + (SIN(((PI() / 2) - RADIANS((90 - locations.lat)))) *
                      SIN(((PI() / 2) - RADIANS(90 - -33.737885))))))
               )
           ) < 500
) GROUP BY shops.id
 ORDER BY locations.id DESC
 LIMIT 100
```